# Absolute element on the top of relative element hover and on-click problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with an absolute element. This element is the `floating-count` which is on the top of the navigation.

Problem is when I hover my mouse on `floating-count` element, the drop-down arrow also is hovering (it should suppose to hover or change color when the navigation hovers). Then when I am clicking the `floating-count` element the drop-down navigation also showing (it should suppose to show when the navigation was clicked).

I tried changing (playing with it as I expect to see the solution) and adding z-index to the elements but I am confused with it.

Code here:

```js
$('.mnav').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).children('.dpdown').is(":hidden")) {

    console.log('show');
    $(this).children('.dpdown').slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    $(this).children('.dpdown').slideUp("fast");

    console.log('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
li.mnav,
.navigation ul.right li.mnav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

a.text-link,
.navigation ul.right li.mnav a.text-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-arrow {
  background: yellow;
}

.nav-arrow:after {
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-top-color: #1b6b00;
  border-width: 8px;
}

.floating-count {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  top: -12px;
  right: -2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.dpdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dpdown ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #eaf2ac;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dpdown ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #1b6b00;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

ul.right {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #208100;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.right li.mnav:hover,
.navigation ul.right li.mnav a.text-link:hover {
  color: #ffea00;
}

.dpdown:hover>.nav-arrow:after {
  color: #ffea00;
}

.navigation .mnav:hover>.nav-arrow:after {
  border-top-color: #ffea00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul class="right">
    <li class="mnav">

      <a href="javascript:;" class="text-link">Drop Down</a><span class="nav-arrow"></span>
      <span class="floating-count-wrap"><a class="floating-count" href="/#count">2</a></span>

      <div class="dpdown">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">B</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">C</a></li>
          <li><a href="/">D</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Try it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzs4r5do/1/):

Comment: *"it should suppose to show when the navigation was clicked"* What selector is it when you say, *"navigation"*? Is it `.mnav` or...`.navigation`?

Comment: it is the `.mnav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the hover style based on `.mnav` and the js dropdown triggered by `.mnav` but `.floating-count-wrap` is a child of `.mnav` so it is triggering those events.

I adjusted the css and js to use `.mnav .test-link` as the selector. I also had to make the css rule use sibling and not parent selection. Similarily, in the js, the selector for the dropdown is no longer a child of `$(this)` so I updated that to `$(this).parent()`

[updated js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82qwfnjt/5/)

js

```
$('.mnav .text-link').on('click', function() { ... });
```

css

```
.navigation .mnav .text-link:hover + .nav-arrow:after { ... }
```

Comment: On-click event is not functioning.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to select the dropdown

Comment: not working either. The dropdown menu is not showing when clicking the navigation link.

Comment: Take a look now xkev - I didn't realize jsfiddle was adding a new number to the link each time, and the latest one is https://jsfiddle.net/82qwfnjt/5/ - I updated the answer